# The current type, Proyecto.ServiceLayer.Interface.IMenuService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, unity

tengo el siguiente problema, desde que hice un cambio de branch  en mi proyecto, el cual corro sobre .net 4.6.1 (probé ya subiendo y bajando de version y actualizando las librerias de unity, e incluso borrando y volviendo a clonar el proyecto), y es que ya con un par de  interfaces me viene haciendo este mismo problema

```
    [InvalidOperationException: The current type, Proyecto.ServiceLayer.Interface.IMenuService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?]
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.DynamicMethod.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext context) +185
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +46
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.DynamicMethod.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.DynamicMethod.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +10
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +190
   Unity.Container.StrategyChain.BuildUp(IBuilderContext builderContext) +131
   Unity.Policy.BuildPlanPolicyExtensions.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuildPlanPolicy policy, IBuilderContext context) +17
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey, Action`1 childCustomizationBlock) +121
   Unity.ResolverPolicy.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +57
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +196
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.DynamicMethod.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.DynamicMethod.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +10
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +190
   Unity.Container.StrategyChain.BuildUp(IBuilderContext builderContext) +131
   Unity.Policy.BuildPlanPolicyExtensions.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuildPlanPolicy policy, IBuilderContext context) +17
   Unity.UnityContainer.BuildUp(Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +206

[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'Proyecto.Web.Controllers.MenuController', name = '(none)'.
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Precission.CiudadDigital.ServiceLayer.Interface.IMenuService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

lei por ahi que posiblemente el problema se podria dar por migraciones que esten pendientes, pero no tengo ninguna, y todas las dependencias están resueltas, pero el problema persiste sin razón alguna.
adjunto mi clase de unity config.

public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

```
    //UoW
    container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

    //ASP.NET Identity 2.0
    container.RegisterType<UserManager<GuidApplicationUser, Guid>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUserStore<GuidApplicationUser, Guid>, GuidUserStore>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<RoleManager<GuidRole, Guid>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IRoleStore<GuidRole, Guid>, GuidRoleStore>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    //container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());

    //Repositories
    container.RegisterType<IMenuRepository, MenuRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IRoleActionRepository, RoleActionRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>(new 
    container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUserRoleRepository, UserRoleRepository>(new 

    //Services
    container.RegisterType<ICategoryForNewsService, CategoryForNewsService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IMenuService, MenuService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsCategoryInterestService, NewsCategoryInterestService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsCategoryService, NewsCategoryService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsEventService, NewsEventService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsImageService, NewsImageService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsLandmarkService, NewsLandmarkService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsLinkService, NewsLinkService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsMetadataService, NewsMetadataService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsMetavalueService, NewsMetavalueService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<INewsService, NewsService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IRequestService, RequestService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IRequestTypeService, RequestTypeService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IRoleActionService, RoleActionService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IRoleService, RoleService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUserRoleService, UserRoleService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());


    container.RegisterType(typeof(GenericMetavalueService<>), typeof(GenericMetavalueService<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType(typeof(GenericMetadataService<>), typeof(GenericMetadataService<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType(typeof(CategorizableEntityService<>), typeof(CategorizableEntityService<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType(typeof(GenericCategoryAssociationService<>), typeof(GenericCategoryAssociationService<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType(typeof(GenericImageAssociationService<>), typeof(GenericImageAssociationService<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType(typeof(GenericLinkAssociationService<>), typeof(GenericLinkAssociationService<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31282343/4092887).

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave justamente, lo vi, y de ahi me guie para las primeras posibilidades, pero no funciono

Comment: si revisas el constructor de MenuController, que interfaces visualizas se estan inyectando? valida que estas esten correctamente definidas en el container de unity

Comment: @LeandroTuttini estan todas correctas, ya que el proyecto antes de cambiar de branch, estaba funcionando con total normalidad

Comment: pues parece que al cambiar de branch algo quedo en algun otro y no se paso algo del codigo, sino no tendrias este mensaje. Podrias ver de volver al otro branch y validar que ejecuta correctamente, si lo hace entonces revisar que commit hay de diferencia y analizar ese codigo que esta faltando

Comment: @LeandroTuttini lo intente tambien, y siguio dando problemas, aparentemente, quedo algo dando vueltas y me rompio ambos branches, o bien hay algo en vs que me estaria rompiendo todo el proyecto, ya que tambien acabo de copiar todo a un proyecto nuevo, y continua el error

Comment: No sé si sirva de mucho, pero a veces según el versionador que usas suele pasar, cierra unity y elimina todos los archivos .meta y vuélvelo a abrir... a veces los meta hacen que las cosas queden flotando...

Comment: Hola, viendo el mensaje de error veo que `IMenuService` lo tienes declarado en dos namespaces. Uno en `Proyecto.ServiceLayer.Interface.IMenuService` y el otro en `Precission.CiudadDigital.ServiceLayer.Interface.IMenuService`. En el código donde haces el registro del la clase que implementa el interfaz no veo a cuál de estos namespace haces referencia. Puedes poner el código completo?